# Autoconf/Automake conditionals and dist rules

Tags: latex, makefile, autoconf, automake

I recently started using autoconf and automake for a project I'm working on. The project's documentation is written in LaTeX. Since I don't want to have LaTeX as a dependency I want to check the presence of the *pdflatex* binary with autoconf and then use that information in the *Makefile.am* to decide whether to simply copy the *.tex* file to the documentation directory, or to generate the PDF and copy both.

This is the relevant section in *configure.ac*:

```
# Check for presence of pdfLaTeX
AC_CHECK_PROG(PDFLATEX, pdflatex, pdflatex)
if test -z "$PDFLATEX"; then
  AC_MSG_WARN([Unable to create PDF version of the user manual.])
fi

AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_PDFLATEX], test -n "$PDFLATEX")
```

In the *doc/* directory I have the following *Makefile.am*:

```
docfiles = manual.tex QuickStart.txt

if HAVE_PDFLATEX
docfiles += manual.pdf
MANNAME = manual
MANTEXSRC = $(MANNAME).tex
MANAUX = $(MANNAME).aux
MANPDF = $(MANNAME).pdf

CLEANFILES = $(MANPDF) $(MANNAME).log $(MANNAME).idx $(MANNAME).out \
 $(MANNAME).toc $(MANAUX)

$(MANPDF): $(srcdir)/$(MANTEXSRC)
    $(PDFLATEX) $<
endif

dist_doc_DATA = $(docfiles)
```

This setup works when *pdflatex* is present, but when it is absent running *make* works, but *make distcheck* asks for a way to build the PDF file:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `manual.pdf', needed by `distdir'.  Stop.
```

Looking in the *Makefile* that automake generated I see:

```
#am__append_1 = manual.pdf
am__dist_doc_DATA_DIST = manual.tex QuickStart.txt manual.pdf
```

and further down I find:

```
docfiles = manual.tex QuickStart.txt $(am__append_1)
#MANNAME = manual
#MANTEXSRC = $(MANNAME).tex
#MANAUX = $(MANNAME).aux
#MANPDF = $(MANNAME).pdf
#CLEANFILES = $(MANPDF) $(MANNAME).log $(MANNAME).idx $(MANNAME).out \
# $(MANNAME).toc $(MANAUX) .btmp

dist_doc_DATA = $(docfiles)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're conditionally "distributing" `manual.pdf`, and automake's rather conservative about dist rules. Try this:

```
if HAVE_PDFLATEX
doc_DATA = manual.pdf
# Rest of your stuff...
endif
```